Save date in Persian Calendar format at SQL
I have a DateTimePicker in my windows form app which show the date in Persian Calendar. But when I want to insert date in my table which is date type, it saves it as Gregorian date.
There are many functions to convert Persian Date to Gregorian date, and the other way.
but I need it to store directly in DB

can you upload a photo of your window form with calendar?

Not a precise duplicate to your database storage question, but on the conversion part: How convert Gregorian date to Persian date?

The database is just saving a moment in time, how you format the components and represent where the stars were at that moment in the time stream of the universe is a matter for front end conversion

Do yourself a favor and abandon this idea. You will regret going down this path. As @flackoverstow said, the date in the database is just a number. But it's a number that the database can work with efficiently. The date has to be converted, whatever format you want it in. If the idea is to have it display Persian format when you're in SQL Management Studio, then change the display options in that program.

How I can changed the options in SQL Management Studio to show the Date type columns in Persian Calendar?

Perhaps a static helper will help you:
static class PersianCalendarHelper
{
    private static PersianCalendar pc = new();
    public static string ToPersian(this DateTime dt) =>
        $"{pc.GetYear(dt):D4}-{pc.GetMonth(dt):D2}-{pc.GetDayOfMonth(dt):D2}";
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dt = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToPersian());
    }
}

Output:
2024-11-10
1403-08-20


I would like to dissuade you from storing time in any format other than UTC. You can always set the calendar and the time zone offset when displaying information. This way you will save the code from unnecessary conversions and minimize possible errors associated with calculating time spans (especially if you plan to work with different time zones and/or daylight saving time is in effect in your country).
